# How to add a message to the "Preview" in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal

With a CCK form that any user is able to acccess at the bottom there is a "Preview" button that allows the user to preview the changes they make and scrolling down below the preview shows them the form/fields they can edit.

For large forms with input there is not a clear message that says that the original form they filled out is below the preview... how can I add a message at the top of the Preview that says "Scroll down below the preview to edit the form you submitted?"

Comment: for best result post it on drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the FORM which you are using is of either `BLOCK` or `PAGE` or `CUSTOM CONTENT` type.
All you need to do is check out the `.tpl.php` file. In there you can Easily modify and display any type of content you want.

Just check out for the function which prints the Form and `echo` your message above that.